# Filling a JavaScript variable with the return value from a php function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
        $(document).ready(function(){

        //let's create arrays
        var cardio = [
            {display: "Bicicleta Reclinada", value: "bicicleta reclinada" },
            {display: "Bicicleta vertical", value: "bicicleta vertical" },
            {display: "Cinta", value: "cinta" },
            {display: "Eliptica", value: "eliptica" },
            {display: "Remo", value: "remo" }];

        var fuerza = [
            {display: "Arm Curl", value: "arm curl" },
            {display: "Poleas Cruzadas", value: "poleas cruzadas" },
            {display: "Pectoral", value: "pectoral" },
            {display: "Cauliflower", value: "cauliflower" }];

        var deportes = [
            {display: "Frozen yogurt", value: "frozen-yogurt" },
            {display: "Booza", value: "booza" },
            {display: "Frozen yogurt", value: "frozen-yogurt" },
            {display: "Ice milk", value: "ice-milk" }];

        var clases = [
            {display: "Frozen yogurt", value: "frozen-yogurt" },
            {display: "Booza", value: "booza" },
            {display: "Frozen yogurt", value: "frozen-yogurt" },
            {display: "Ice milk", value: "ice-milk" }];         
    </script>
```

I have a function in php: `CommonFunctions::returnEjercicio(x);` which returns an array with the values I wanna put in the display and value fields of each variable of the JavaScript when I set `x = nameOfVariable`.

The function returns the following when the input is set to: *cardio*:

> array(5) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(19) "Bicicleta Reclinada" [1]=> string(19) "bicicleta reclinada" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(18) "Bicicleta Vertical" [1]=> string(18) "bicicleta vertical" } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "Cinta" [1]=> string(5) "cinta" } [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "Eliptica" [1]=> string(8) "eliptica" } [4]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "Remo" [1]=> string(4) "remo" } }

So it returns an array of arrays in which the first value (index 0) should go to the **display** and the second value (index 1) to the **value** of the Javascript variable.

My question is: How can I call this php function from the Javascript code and then use the return values to assign the Javascript variables.

Comment: You can echo the result of `json_encode` in javascript from php or you can use ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP code bellow

```
<?php
    foreach($returned_array as $element) {
        echo "{display: '" . $element[0] . "', value: '" . $element[1] . "' },';
    }
?>
```

Will output this

```
{display: "Bicicleta Reclinada", value: "bicicleta reclinada" },
{display: "Bicicleta vertical", value: "bicicleta vertical" },
{display: "Cinta", value: "cinta" },
{display: "Eliptica", value: "eliptica" },
{display: "Remo", value: "remo" },
```

You just need to wrap this inside `[` and `]` to get one of your array.

But I don't know how you can generate `cardio`, `fuerza`, `deportes` and `clases`.

Comment: shall I call the PHP function inside or outside the Javascript?

Comment: In a javascript code inside a PHP file.. But please, can you show us the returned array format ?

Comment: Just added the return parameters to the post